# Issues with attempting to enter intents

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I'm having an issue when attempting to enter specific intents based on the value of a property.

I currently have a question that gets asked, which then fires off to the Microsoft Translator via a HTTP Request and from that, it fires off to the LUIS API with that text.

After that, I would like to enter an intent based on the top intent that the LUIS API Call brought back.

I have the Translator and The LUIS API bringing back values and I can output these using Send Responses:
[image] [image]

However, when I attempt to call an intent based on the value of the property, I just get an Object Reference error:

[image]
[image]

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so am I going about this entirely the wrong way causing more issues for myself?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. Do I summarize it correctly as following?

1. You start a main dialog. In that dialog you take some user input.
2. You translate the input, and *manually* send the the translated text off to LUIS for intent recognition.
3. Based on the recognized intent, you want to start a specific sub dialog.

I don't believe you can just 'call an intent'. An intent is the result of a LUIS or Regex recognizer, which is processed automatically by Bot Framework. The recognizer is processed at every *user input*. There is no need to call LUIS yourself as a HTTP request. The recognizer (LUIS or RegEx) is configured on the main dialog properties in Bot Framework Composer:

[image]

Although in this case it looks like you are manually doing the LUIS intent recognition, because you want to do translation upfront. To achieve that scenario with the built-in recognizer, you would need a translation middleware. There is a short discussion going on [here on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3514) about translation middleware for Bot Framework Composer, although the sample code is not ready yet.

While there is no code samples for the translation middleware yet, I believe what could already help you today is to start a subdialog based on the recognized intent, similar to what you already show in your screenshots.
Basically instead of "Send a response" at the end of your dialog, you would have something following like:

[image]

My sample here uses user input instead of the recognized intent. You would replace the user input with your intent variable instead. Based on the recognized intent, you would be able to spin up a specific dialog to handle that recognized intent.

[image]

The result would look something like:

[image]

About triggers, what you currently configured in your screenshot shows "no editor for null". I believe this might cause the "object reference" issue. Normally it should display a trigger phrase. For example, the below means:

- If *user* inputs the text "triggerphrase"
- And the dialog variable 'topintent' was previously set to 'test', then run this trigger.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're saying. Thanks for your help. I shall take a look into this :)